# Data Loader converting & to &amp; and throwing error

Tags: data-loader, csv, python

I am trying to load a csv file (encoded as UTF-8) into the salesforce Data Loader. One of the values in the csv file is a string reading "Biotechnology & Science". When I try loading the csv file, I receive the following error.

```
bad value for restricted picklist field: Biotechnology &amp; Science
```

I have referenced Salesforce knowledge articles such as [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_import_dataloader_specialchars.htm&type=5), but none have helped. I have tried checking off the Data Loader's `"Read all CSVs with UTF-8 encoding"` checkbox but it does not resolve the issue. Manually enclosing the value in double quotes (`"`) does not help either.

The csv file when opened with Notepad shows the following:

```
False,3,Biotechnology & Science,Jacksonville University,
```

(This is only a snippit of the data but coveres the value discussed)

I am creating the csv file via a Python 3 script using the Pandas .to_csv() method, which defaults encoding to UTF-8. I am operating on a Windows 10 computer.

Comment: The `&amp;` in the response may be just a by product of how error messages are returned. Maybe try the fixes mentioned in [Error 'Bad value for restricted picklist field' when creating records](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000250168&language=en_US&type=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to stumble upon the answer, and it is embarrassingly simple. The API for the picklist value was "Biotechnology", while the value label was "Biotechnology & Science". The ampersand was not causing the issue, the API was. I fixed the API and everything works fine.